# Incrementing ratio button id in for loop

Tags: angular

In a for loop i'm rendering radio buttons, but i need to increment the  radio button id to `radio1,radio2 and so on`. how can i do it ?

Please help.

```html
<span class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio" *ngFor="let demand of Demands">
            <input id="radio1" name="radio" [(ngModel)]="demandValue" [value]="demand.value" type="radio">
            <span class="radioLabel"><label class="custom-control-description" for="radio1">{{demand.name}}</label></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<span class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio" *ngFor="let demand of Demands; let i = index;">
    <input id="radio{{i}}" name="radio" [(ngModel)]="demandValue" [value]="demand.value" type="radio">
    <span class="radioLabel">
        <label class="custom-control-description" for="radio{{i}}">{{demand.name}}</label>
    </span>
</span>
```

I added the index in for loop and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id value using the `attr.id` attribute on input.

The index value can be extracted from the *ngFor. `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"`

```
<span class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio" *ngFor="let demand of Demands; let i = index">
            <input attr.id={{'radio' + i}} name="radio" [(ngModel)]="demandValue" [value]="demand.value" type="radio">
            <span class="radioLabel"><label class="custom-control-description" for="radio1">{{demand.name}}</label></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> use index `let i = index;` and provide it to your id. But your `ngModel` and `ngValue` objects should be coming from your `Demands` array. Otherwise if you select the value in a radio button, it will affect to all radio buttons.

Try this.

```html
<span class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio" *ngFor="let demand of Demands; let i = index;">
            <input id="radio{{I + 1 }}" name="radio" [(ngModel)]="demandValue" [value]="demand.value" type="radio">
            <span class="radioLabel"><label class="custom-control-description" for="radio{{I + 1}}">{{demand.name}}</label></span>
</span>
```